# How do I map a function call from c++ to Java using JavaCpp?

Tags: java, c++, javacpp

I have a `c++` header file which contains some functions that the `c++` code calls. These function should be mapped to corresponding `Java` functions.
So it is a bit like callbacks, but I cannot figure out how to map them in `JavaCpp`.

So for instance we have a header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef void (*F_ADDDCALLBACK)(uint32_t arg1, uint32_t arg2, int8_t *arg3);
extern F_ADDDCALLBACK m_CB;

void F_RegisterCallbacks(F_ADDDCALLBACK cb);
void F_Init();
void F_SomeOtherFunction(uint32_t arg1, uint8_t *arg2);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

When these functions are called from some `c++` code, it should in turn call some `java` code.
How do I map this in `JavaCpp`?

Comment: You can refer to JNI (Java Native Interface). That will help you.

Comment: see http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077513/learn-java/java-tip-17--integrating-java-with-c--.html

Comment: Please follow the instructions here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/Create-New-Presets

Answer (score -1):

First create a java file where you need to define your own functions. then use `javah` utility which comes with `jdk` to generate `c` header files. By including this header files you need to proceed with your `c` code.

Please refer to `JNI` (Java Native Interface) for further information.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaha%2Fjniex.htm

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/jniTOC.html

Comment: But I'm using `javacpp`so I need a way to map it with that, preferably.